# Actually using a cljsjs package

Tags: clojure, material-design, clojurescript

I'm having trouble understanding how to go from installing to using a cljsjs package. I am using the standard figwheel template, and I've made a little progress learning it, but now I'd like to use some 3rd party JS, and while cljsjs looks like the ticket, I can't find a clear example of how to actually use the packages.

I'm attempting to use the material package, to start with (http://material-ui.com). I'd like to just display a simple button to start.

I've added the `[cljsjs/material "1.0.4-0"]` to my project.clj, and lein installs it....now what?

Where and when should I `(:require [cljsjs.material])` ?

How would I then create a `<FlatButton>` component, or whatever?

I see a `resources/public/js/compiled/out/material.inc.js` with what appears to be the full source for material - how do I use it?

Thanks in advance to any kind soul taking pity on a cljs beginner. It is  *incredibly* appreciated. If there is anything out there that answers my question that my googling somehow missed, I apologize in advance.

Comment: Check out this for an example: https://github.com/not-much-io/papyri-demo

Comment: I'm using material at getmdl.io, and I'm having the same troubles as you, did you ever figure out how to actually add a component? I can't seem to import `material` correctly, and anything I add a material class to, it doesn't register...

Comment: Did you checkout out the papyri-demo example that Andre posted above? It's an example that shows how to use it. It uses an interval to update the DOM, which is a little weird, but appears to work.

Answer (score 1):

The package `[cljsjs/material]` you're referencing does *NOT* use http://material-ui.com/ but instead uses: http://www.getmdl.io/

So there is NO `<FlatButton>`.

Comment: Well, then, there's my first problem.... THANKS for the demo you showed in the comment above. Is that the canonical way to use this particular package? Try to update the dom on an interval? I will study that, thanks again.

Comment: Admittedly, the cljsjs package description should definitely state that. You should file a Pull request for clarifying the readme.

Answer (score 0):

A primer on actually using cljsjs packages can be found here:

https://github.com/cljsjs/packages/wiki/Using-Packages

To use the `material-ui` package for example:

- Put `[cljsjs/material-ui "3.9.1-0"]` in the `:dependencies` section of your `project.clj` file (make sure you update the version number to latest).
- Require the cljsjs package in the `(ns)` section of your code: `(:require material-ui)`
- Finally, you can **reference the imported JavaScript objects directly** by name: `js/MaterialUI`

It is sometimes difficult to figure out the JavaScript names. Generally you need to refer to the original JS package.

In the case of `material-ui` specifically, there are `:global-exports` helper mappings [which you can see here](https://github.com/cljsjs/packages/blob/master/material-ui/build.boot#L39), and these allow you to reference the library more conveniently and directly with `material-ui`.

*Note that it is also quite often possible to [import npm modules directly](https://clojurescript.org/reference/compiler-options#npm-deps) now with `:npm-deps`.*